# How to return object interface with variable as a key in TypeScript? Type is not assignable to type error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following type and interfaces.

```
type ColVal = [{
    col: string
}, {
    val: string
}]

interface IEquals {
    eq: ColVal,
}

interface INotEquals {
    ne: ColVal,
}
```

And I have the following function:

```
const getOperation = (col: string, val: string, operation: string): IEquals | INotEquals => {
    let op: 'eq' | 'ne' = operation === 'Equals' ? 'eq' : 'ne';
    return {
        [op]: [{
            col,
        }, {
            val,
        }]
    };
};
```

But I get the error `Type '{ [x: string]: ({ col: string } | { val: string; })[]; }' is not assignable to 'IEquals | INotEquals'.`

If I change `[op]` to `['eq']` or `['ne']`, the error goes away. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Here is the TypeScript playground for you guys to see the issue: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwGoEMFQLxQNoG8BQURUAxogFxQDOwATgJYB2A5vgL4A0UBxUAbmko0GLdgF18%20JsAi0AZihLQAkgFEAjgFc0VboWIR1leMjQd2k6bIVKoygHJxgG7Ql09ijCMcSoE5tkkyRhooZghgAHlIWhRgejhGTCgACjIEITomZi4BDOosli44GLiExkyRZgBKSjUtHSgAHztHZwa3TAA%20PV4ECKgSygByQ2HmqGGvcawS2TLEzAwsYZcdcYB%20SbGoEemAbn0iWgjNWiSPXiJsErFKPCOr3nTzJ6JOXrfePNe3tgleGxDkD9EA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently a design limitation of TypeScript that computed properties of union types have their key widened all the way to `string` by the compiler.  So an object literal like `{[Math.random()<0.5 ? "a" : "b"]: 123}` is inferred by the compiler to be of the type `{[k: string]:number}` instead of the more specific `{a: number} | {b: number}`.

Both [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) and [microsoft/TypeScript#21030](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21030) concern this issue.   It looks like there was some attempt to address it at one point, [microsoft/TypeScript#21070](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21070)) but it fizzled out.

I don't know if it will ever be addressed, but for now you'll have to work around it.

---

The least disruptive (and least type safe) workaround this is just to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that the return value is of the appropriate type.  In this case the compiler sees the return value is of a type that's so wide that it doesn't even see it as related to `IEquals | INotEquals`.  So you'll have to assert through some intermediate type... might as well just use `any`, the ultimate "just make it work" type:

```
const getOperationAssert = (col: string, val: string, operation: string): IEquals | INotEquals => {
    let op: 'eq' | 'ne' = operation === 'Equals' ? 'eq' : 'ne';
    return {
        [op]: [{
            col,
        }, {
            val,
        }]
    } as any; //  I'm smarter than the compiler 
};
```

---

Another idea is to manually implement a helper function that behaves the way computed properties "should" behave.  Like this:

```
function computedProp<K extends PropertyKey, V>(key: K, val: V): { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: V } }[K];
function computedProp(key: PropertyKey, val: any) {
    return { [key]: val };
}
```

So if you call `computedProp(Math.random()<0.5 ? "a" : "b", 123)`, the implementation just makes an object with a computed property, but the typing is such that it returns `{a: number} | {b: number}`.  Then your `getOperation()` becomes:

```
const getOperationHelper = (col: string, val: string, operation: string): IEquals | INotEquals => {
    let op: 'eq' | 'ne' = operation === 'Equals' ? 'eq' : 'ne';
    return computedProp(op, [{
        col,
    }, {
        val,
    }]);
};
```

---

Finally, if you're willing to refactor, you could consider not using computed properties at all.  Store your `ColVal` value in a variable, and then return it as the property of either an object literal with a literal `eq` key or one with a literal `ne` key.  The compiler can follow that flow much more accurately and can verify it as safe:

```
const getOperationRefactor = (col: string, val: string, operation: string): IEquals | INotEquals => {
    let op: 'eq' | 'ne' = operation === 'Equals' ? 'eq' : 'ne';
    const colVal: ColVal = [{ col }, { val }];
    return (operation === 'Equals') ? { eq: colVal } : { ne: colVal };
};
```

---

Hopefully one of those works for you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGwGoEMFQLxQNoG8BQURUAxogFxQDOwATgJYB2A5vgL4A0UBxUAbmko0GLdgF18+JsAi0AZihLQAkgFEAjgFc0VboWIR1leMjQd2k6bIVKoygHJxgG7Ql09ijCMcSoE5tkkyRhooZghgAHlIWhRgejhGAEEqKllgTCgACjIEITomZi4BPOoCli44GLiExnyRZgBKSjUtHSgAHztHZza3TAA+PV4ECKgqygByQ0nOqEmvWawq2RrEzAwsSZcdWYB+eZmoKcWAbn0iWgjNWkZh3mJsKrFKPAuH3lzzD6JOe5-iCVvj82GIoO82FAULoUIwQKcoAB6RFQQB8G4BkXbskwAttRsShaDJaFBgAALWEk0nQMjYsD0UbE9jnfByTSMEjxdY0sCaGQAEwACrQqgAeADSUAgAA8ZIw+bohStCSAxRAQFwkAMsgBrNWUMXFQRQJDNbg4AVQJhQMUvM3YACKlruAttSCgkLY2Bt51Z7M5d25vIgguFYB1eqgipioFV6v4RthIEa-ygV2ANzuuBwupAtpK7vOgXwwVC4Si1X9AAkIAgYpkchQyg1DaVhIVKhXavVCqbWq5dF0HE4dv0MEMPERRhkJod1LMugsIEtxp31pstiOqPtZ7MTkvzrw0xnSHBaUGQ1UslUuG8AV8IVwJw8gRCxI1C8zi4lSxFoqt-QAShANjAHAxJYA2rblEU8ZQc2K7-l2TY9i0m5zEOvT9oMKZTiuUxHAuiyZEqax3Ou8ybtu0xzsc8xnO8JYZLkfg+KY6BYHgJ7oH8Wb5qCB7EEetzZCR-obBufRbsmBxZoYlDMWg7q0VmXjyb4ilsB++BAA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and explanation. The problem I had at hand, it was difficult for me to google/research the problem at hand because I couldn't have worded it other than a StackOverflow post.