# Typescript return object with computed property from parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to do something like

```
function f<T extends 'a' | 'b'>(t : T): {[t]: ...} {
  return {[t]: ...}
}
```

such that `f('a')` has type `{'a': ...}` and similarly for 'b',
but it makes typescript very angry. I've looked at [Return type is object where key is computed from argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57787831/return-type-is-object-where-key-is-computed-from-argument), [How to return object interface with variable as a key in TypeScript? Type is not assignable to type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505668/how-to-return-object-interface-with-variable-as-a-key-in-typescript-type-is-not), and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), but they haven't been especially helpful.

Is this possible in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

Does this fulfill your needs?

```
type FReturn<T extends string>={
  [key in T]: string;
};

function f<T extends 'a' | 'b'>(t : T): FReturn<T> {
  return {
    [t]: ''
  } as FReturn<T>
}

let x = f('a')

x.a // string
x.b //error


let y = f('b')

y.b //string
y.a //error
```

Comment: I guess; it would be nice if there was a way to do it without the cast